# spam with my own domain

Tags: email, spam

At my work we have a very tricky issue with spam. We use postfix, and recently began to receive several spam mails from our own domain.

This is obviously very prejudicial for us, because many customers could think that those mails were sent by our company.

Does anyone know some guide or solution for this particular problem? The thing is that mail server configuration isn't my expertise, so I'm a bit lost in this.

Comment: Are they only using the from tag with your domain in it or are you saying they are using your mailserver to send spam?

Comment: I don't know exactly... I supposed postfix has some logs files, but as I said, config things isn't my expertise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that what you're seeing is a spammer using your domain name as the "From" address for a particular set of mails.  This is done as a method of bypassing some spam filters (although I don't think it's particularly effective these days, as commercial mail filters still seem to be quite good at recognizing the mails as SPAM)

There's no way to directly stop the spammer from doing this, however I wouldn't worry too much about your customers seeing this as a negative, as it's a common phenomenon (a domain I've got gets this on a fairly regular basis) and not within your control to prevent.

Answer (score 17):

There's no fix for this. Anyone can forge the From: address in an email, and only a technically sophisticated user can detect the forgery.

You could use [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) and/or [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) to increase the chance that ISPs will detect the forgeries and block the emails, but this will only work sometimes.